# This if statement doesn't end once triggered by touch

Tags: unity

I have an if statement that successfully recognizes a touch, but continues executing after the touch has ended.

```
void Update() {

    float currentstep = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, head.Gaze.direction, currentstep, 0.0F);

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
            fingerCount++;
    }

    if (fingerCount > 0){
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
        transform.position += sub_speed * head.Gaze.direction;
        Debug.Log (fingerCount);
    }
}
```

I want the transforms to stop executing once the touch has ended. I'd expect Update to catch that for me. Why isn't it?

Comment: So, where you set fingerCount = 0 after fingerCount++? :). I think it will be always greater than zero once you touch the screen. You should change your check from ended and cancelled to begin and moved. Kindly confirm the keywords for begin and moved. And in case of ended or cancel make fingerCount=0

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things by using GetMouseButton, like this:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
        transform.position += sub_speed * head.Gaze.direction;
        Debug.Log (fingerCount);
```

This will work on touch devices, and execute the if statement while touch is held down.

Comment: No problem, just maybe do a bit more research next time.

Comment: You found the answer to your own question (which is fine). But in the answer you talk to yourself in the second person. Then you are saying thanks to yourself and next, recommending to yourself that you should do a bit more research next time? I'm a bit confused here. :)

Comment: @MAnd He clearly forgot to sign into his other account prior to answering his second accounts question...